# Load complete is never called

Tags: jquery

I have this pice of javascript which loads a html file which contains the divs the logic works on. It is a popop window that should be included in multiple pages.

I have used the exact same approach with success elsewhere.

The problem is that the complete method is never called and when I log the browsers interaction with the server, there are no calls placed.

This is the same in IE9 and FF16.

Do you have a hint to bring me further?

TIA :)

```
function defineEditDocumentWindow(divTag) {
assert($(divTag));
assert(UrlExists('/Documents/EditDocument.htm'));
$(divTag).load('/Documents/EditDocument.htm', null, function (response, status, xhr) {
    alert('hey, we were called');
    if (status == "error") {
        debugger;
    } else {
        debugger;
        var width = 1500;
        var height = 800;

        var initWidgets = function (tab) {
            switch (tab) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    initializePreview();
                    break;
            }
        };
        $('#jqxTabDocumentEditPreview').jqxTabs({ height: 700, width: 1480, theme: 'classic', initTabContent: initWidgets });
        $('#jqxEditDocumentWindow').jqxWindow({ height: height, maxHeight: height, width: width, maxWidth: width, theme: 'classic', autoOpen: true, isModal: true, animationType: 'none' });

        $('#jqxTabDocumentEditPreview').jqxTabs({ keyboardNavigation: false });
        $('#jqxTabDocumentEditPreview').bind('selected', function (event) {
            initializePreview(event);
        });
    }
});
}
```

HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="T24Portal.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ScriptsExternal/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/WaitSignUtil.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqwidgets/styles/jqx.classic.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqwidgets/styles/jqx.classic.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Documents/EditDocument.Main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ScriptsExternal/ba-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ScriptsExternal/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ScriptsExternal/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ScriptsExternal/showdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/AvalonUtil.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            defineEditDocumentWindow("EditDocumentWindowPlaceHolder");
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>

</head>
<body>
   <div id="EditDocumentWindowPlaceHolder">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have an error in the debug console (F12)?

Comment: No, nothing. It appears as if it is ignored :)

Comment: The only solution is that the divTag is not corresponsing to a an existing div HTML element. What is the string of your divTag variable? It should be something like "#myDiv" => `$("#myDiv").load()`

Comment: I have tried to add the html but the editor keeps claiming that it is not formatted properly. Yet I have checked that the div exist and please also note the codeline: assert($(divTag));

Comment: Ok, the callback is not called, but is the page loaded into your div?

Comment: No. actually the code act as if the load never took place. There is no call to the server in the Browser Network log, nothing gets filled and the complete function is never called.
Thanks for your interest. The html has to be available on multiple pages and there is a lot, so it would be very poor to have to duplicate it on each page.

Comment: So, the only solution is that the element doesn't support .load() function or is not found. Can you show me the string of divTag variable?

Comment: I have added the function prototype and the ASP.NET html.

Comment: Oh my god, I missed a hashmark. It works now, thank you so much for your attempt to help me.

Comment: Good to read that, but for the record, I didn't attempt, I helped you when I have written that the divTag variable was false :o)

Comment: people have really stopped reading the code, don't understand the point of 3 up votes

Answer (score 0):

To complete this Q/A ... The proper selector is not being used properly.

The function call:

```
defineEditDocumentWindow("EditDocumentWindowPlaceHolder");
```

should be:

```
defineEditDocumentWindow("#EditDocumentWindowPlaceHolder");
```

*Missed the leading hash mark.*